# Gitlab CI cannot pull image from private docker registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to create a Docker based Gitlab CI runner which pulls the docker images for the build from a private Docker Registry (v2). I cannot make the Gitlab Runner to pull the image from a local Registry, it tries to GET something from a `/v1` API. I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Build failed: Error while pulling image: Get http://registry:5000/v1/repositories/maven/images: dial tcp: lookup registry on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host

Here's a minimal example, using docker-compose and a web browser.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce
    ports:
      - "22:22"
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - registry:registry

  gitlab_runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    links:
      - registry:registry
      - gitlab:gitlab

  registry:
    image: registry:2
```

After the first Gitlab login, I register the runner into the Gitlab instance:

```
root@130d08732613:/# gitlab-runner register
Running in system-mode.                            

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/ci):
http://192.168.61.237:8080/ci         
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
tE_1RKnwkfj2HfHCcrZW
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[130d08732613]: docker
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):

Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=tE_1RKnw
Please enter the executor: docker-ssh+machine, docker, docker-ssh, parallels, shell, ssh, virtualbox, docker+machine:
docker
Please enter the default Docker image (eg. ruby:2.1):
maven:latest
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

After this, I see the Gitlab runner in my Gitlab instance:

[image: Gitlab Runner in Gitlab instance]

After this I push a simple maven image to my newly created Docker repository:

```
vilmosnagy@vnagy-dell:~/$ docker tag maven:3-jdk-7 172.19.0.2:5000/maven:3-jdk7
vilmosnagy@vnagy-dell:~/$ docker push 172.19.0.2:5000/maven:3-jdk7 
The push refers to a repository [172.19.0.2:5000/maven]
79ab7e0adb89: Pushed 
f831784a6a81: Pushed 
b5fc1e09eaa7: Pushed 
446c0d4b63e5: Pushed 
338cb8e0e9ed: Pushed 
d1c800db26c7: Pushed 
42755cf4ee95: Pushed 
3-jdk7: digest: sha256:135e7324ccfc7a360c7641ae20719b068f257647231d037960ae5c4ead0c3771 size: 1794
```

(I got the `172.19.0.2` IP-address from a `docker inspect` command's output)

After this I create a test project in the Gitlab and add a simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: registry:5000/maven:3-jdk-7

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - analyze

maven_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn -version"
```

And after the build the Gitlab gives the error in seen in the beginning of the post.

If I enter into the running gitlab-runner container, I can access the registry under the given URL:

```
vilmosnagy@vnagy-dell:~/$ docker exec -it comptest_gitlab_runner_1 bash
root@c0c5cebcc06f:/# curl http://registry:5000/v2/maven/tags/list
{"name":"maven","tags":["3-jdk7"]}
root@c0c5cebcc06f:/# exit
exit
vilmosnagy@vnagy-dell:~/$
```

But the error still the same:

[image: Gitlab Runner in Gitlab instance]

Do you have any idea how to force the gitlab-runner to use the v2 api of the private registry?

Comment: Have you tried pulling the image from inside the runner? Maybe with the "external" IP? What about pulling the image from the host?

Comment: @mgansler If I enter into the gitlab_runner image (`docker exec -it comptest_gitlab_runner_1 bash`) there is no docker command. But the registry is seen, 'cause I can use the registry's HTTP API with curl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Current Gitlab and Gitlab Runners support this, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#use-a-private-container-registry

On older Gitlab I've solved this with copying an auth key into `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
        "auths": {
                "my.docker.registry.url": {
                        "auth": "dmlsbW9zLm5hZ3k6VGZWNTM2WmhC"
                }
        }
}
```

I've logged into this container from my computer and copied this auth key into the Gitlab Runner's docker container.

Comment: More precise docs are at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

Comment: +Tip : if your private image is the default one, and to forward DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG (the json content sample provided as config.json) directly from gitlab-runner args, cf. [my comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4120#note_1835805452)

Answer (score 1):

What version of docker do you run on Gitlab ?
Also for a v2 registry, you have to explicitly allow insecure registry with a command line switch, or secure your registry using a certificate.

Otherwise Docker fallback to the v1 registry if it gets a security exception.

Comment: The docker version is `1.11.2`, detailed version info is here: http://pastebin.com/g9ma56ME

The insecure registry is set in the host OS as the following: `--insecure-registry registry:5000`. I don't know that the gitlab runner how starts the containers - which docker binary does it uses, in which file should I set the insecure registry inside the runner image, etc. The gitlab_runner image does not have a docker executable on the path, so I do not know where to start.